# web.config URL Rewrite - exclude specific page

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm testing using more modern URLs, e.g. https://cookcomputing.co.uk/test/1234/keywords_go_here instead of https://www.cookcomputing.co.uk/default.asp?page=test&id=1234&name=keywords_go_here but, since the site also uses response.redirect for mobile clients I'm ending up with err_too_many_redirects.

I've added the following to my web.config and it works well on desktop:

```
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?page=test&amp;id={R:1}&amp;name={R:2}" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

However, the site also uses a bit of asp to detect a mobile client and redirects from default.asp to default_mobile.asp which, without the rewrite, also works fine. However, when the two combine, on a mobile we end up with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I suspect I may just need to stop the rewrite rule running after the response.redirect sends is over to default_mobile.asp URLs but I can't for the life of me get a CONDITION to work that will do that.

HELP!!!! Please.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f You can easily skip certain pages via another rewrite rule.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can try clearing your browser's cache and try again, if that doesn't work, you can use the [failed request trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see the details.